# Automatically Blocking Suspicious IPs on Elastic Beanstalk instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an **Elastic Beanstalk instance that is running a Flask app**. I want to know if there is any way through AWS to **automatically block IP addresses** that are doing **unusual activity** on my site.

This could be a range of things, for example:

- Send several GET requests over and over
- Trying to POST without a CSRF

And more. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, for that you would front your EB with application load balancer and  [AWS Web Application Firewall](https://aws.amazon.com/waf/).

This setup is documented in the recent **AWS blog** and other sources:

- [How do I protect my Elastic Beanstalk environment against attacks from known unwanted hosts?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elastic-beanstalk-host-attacks/)
- [Setting up AWS Web Application Firewall (WAF) with Elastic Beanstalk](https://medium.com/finnovate-io/setting-up-aws-web-application-firewall-waf-with-elastic-beanstalk-6243dc7755ea)
- [Guidelines for Implementing AWS WAF](https://d1.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/guidelines-implementing-aws-waf.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for this answer. In your last link, it says that WAF can be setup with an application load balancer or connected to CloudFront. What is the difference between these two approaches?

Comment: @JJT Hi. ALB is load balancer. It is on by default if you use high-availability EB environment. So you don't really need CF, if you already have ALB. CF is a CDN, and it would be useful if you have single-instance EB environment and don't need a load balancer (several instances).

Comment: @JJT No problem. Glad could help :-)

Comment: Actually, one question I had: would this also block people after a number of unsuccesful login attempts? Or should I post a new question on this?

Comment: @JJT Login to your application? WAF would be infront of your EB. So if a user can perform a login action, they would have already passed WAF. Yes, you can make new question, so other can provide their insights as well.

Comment: Got it. But, if a bot for example was to make 100s of post requests, would it be blocked? I guess what I am asking is what does WAF explicitly do? Thanks for the help!

Comment: @JJT WAF can be customize with Rules, and the rules can include `Count` value of requests. You can have a look at [WAF docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/waf-chapter.html) for more details and check if it would suite you. If not, then you would have to look at some third party solutions or develop your own.

Comment: Got it, and what does this `Count` mean? Really thankful for the help!!

Comment: @JJT You can have rules base on count of requests. Thus, if the requests are to frequent from one IP, you can reject them.

Comment: @JJT Just have a look at the docs. I also don't remember every detail of WAF setup :-(

Comment: No problem! Figured it out!